# Index not incrementing while implementing an Iterator

Tags: java, iterator

So I made a  class DiceCollection which implements an Iterator and its classes. While doing the unit tests, my next() method doesn't seem to increment my index, and I'm not sure what's the reason behind that.

```
public class DiceCollection implements Iterator<De> {
 public int position = 0;
 public int endPosition = 3;
 private De[] diceList;

 @Override
 public boolean hasNext() {
    return position < endPosition;
 }

 @Override
 public De next() {
    De de = diceList[position];     
    position++;
    return de;
 }
}
```

Now when calling the next() method, my position index stays the same:

```
    Iterator<De> iter = des.creerIterateur();
    System.out.println(iter.hasNext());
    System.out.println(des.position + "/" + des.endPosition);
    System.out.println(iter.next());
    System.out.println(des.position + "/" + des.endPosition);
    System.out.println(iter.hasNext());
    System.out.println(iter.next());
    System.out.println(des.position + "/" + des.endPosition);
    System.out.println(iter.hasNext());
    System.out.println(iter.next());
    System.out.println(iter.hasNext());
    System.out.println(iter.next()); //null
```

I get this output:

```
true
0/3
De [valeur=0, nbFaces=6]
0/3
true
De [valeur=0, nbFaces=8]
0/3
true
De [valeur=0, nbFaces=10]
true
null
```

Comment: Where did you assign and populate `diceList`?

Comment: `private De[] diceList;` is (always) `null` ... `endPosition` (seemingly/always) `3`

Comment: ..your iterator should have (not null) reverence on your "iterable object", and get the end position from it (at intialization time ...0 is ok as a start position)

Comment: not to scare you off, but for further studies: [the "full blown" implementation of (e.g.) ArrayList.iterator()](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l825) (also navigable from your IDE) ...and of course (inside) very specific to ArrayList

Comment: Thank you I will certainly give it a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the next() method on the iter object while printing the position attribute of the des object. When calling next(), the position attribute of the iter object changes, but not the des.position attribute.

```
System.out.println(des.next());
System.out.println(des.position + "/" + des.endPosition);
```

Should print the correct values.

Comment: That makes sense, I wasn't using the next() that I implemented. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine.  I tested it like this.  But I'm not certain how you were feeding values to the private array.  Here is how you should be implementing it.

```
        Dice[] array = {new Dice(1), new Dice(2)};
        DiceCollection d = new DiceCollection(array);
        Iterator<Dice> it = d.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(it.next());
        }
        System.out.println("Using iterable");
        // And since iterable has been implemented.
        for (Dice di : d) {
           System.out.println(di);
        }


class Dice {
    int v;
    public Dice(int v) {
        this.v = v;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return v +"";
    }
}

class DiceCollection implements Iterable<Dice> {
    private Dice[] diceList;

    public DiceCollection(Dice[] arr) {
        diceList = arr;
    }

    private class MyIterator implements Iterator<Dice> {

        private int position = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return position < diceList.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Dice next() {
            Dice de = diceList[position];
            position++;
            return de;
        }
    }

    public Iterator<Dice> iterator() {
        return new MyIterator();
    }
}
```

Comment: I provided some additional info that may help.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and answer. I just chose to skip the part where I am populating my collection as I didn't deem it valuable to my problem. Turned out I was calling the Iterator next() rather than my overridden next(), and thus my issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The code is working, but you're looking at the wrong object's values.  Only the values inside **iter** are changing. Try this?

```
 Iterator<De> iter = des.creerIterateur();
System.out.println(iter.hasNext());
System.out.println(iter.position + "/" + iter.endPosition);
System.out.println(iter.next());
System.out.println(iter.position + "/" + iter.endPosition);
System.out.println(iter.hasNext());
System.out.println(iter.next());
System.out.println(iter.position + "/" + iter.endPosition);
System.out.println(iter.hasNext());
System.out.println(iter.next());
System.out.println(iter.hasNext());
System.out.println(iter.next()); //null
```